# How to nest [FromHeader] validated models in ASP NET

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, validation

For my API, I have three headers, and all three are used for almost all endpoints. However some endpoints do not required all three. But for each endpoint, it will require whichever headers to be present.

I want to be able to create models to validate each header individually, and then create another model to wrap those together, so that it'll be useful to specify just a single model as most endpoint needs all three to be validated, and only a handful need one or two.

My goal is to make the method signature a bit cleaner and avoid duplicate code.

```
// Models
public class MainId
{
    [FromHeader(Name = "id")]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserId
{
    [FromHeader(Name = "userId")]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class OtherId
{
    [FromHeader(Name = "otherId")]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class AllHeaders
{
    [FromHeader]
    public MainId MainId { get; set; }
    
    [FromHeader]
    public UserId UserId { get; set; }

    [FromHeader]
    public OtherId OtherId { get; set; }
}



// Controllers
[ApiController]
public class MyController: ControllerBase 
{
    [HttpGet("/allThree")]
    public string allThree([FromHeader] AllHeaders headers)
    {
        // be able to access all three headers here
        string h1 = headers.MainId.Id;
        string h2 = headers.UserId.Id;
        string h3 = headers.OtherId.Id;
    }

    // I know I can do the above like so, but if I ever want to add headers, it just makes the function signature sloppier
    [HttpGet("allThreeV2")]
    public string allThreeV2([FromHeader] MainId mainId, [FromHeader] UserId userId, [FromHeader] OtherId otherId)
    {
        // can access all three
        string h1 = mainId.Id;
        string h2 = userId.Id;
        string h3 = userId.Id;
    }

    [HttpGet("/singleHeader")]
    public string oneHeader([FromHeader] MainId mainId)
    {
        // be able to access the one header here
        string h1 = mainId.Id;
    }
}
```

There errors that I am encountering is either the AllHeaders is null, and if I omit [FromHeader] there, then the controller will return a 415 because it is looking for those inside classes of AllHeaders instead of the fields inside of those inside classes.

I am wondering if this modularity is achievable, or if I can structure the models in another way to achieve this. I would hope that the validator can somehow flatten down the AllHeaders class to populate the inside most fields.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, this can be achieved in .NET 6 with the following setup:

```
// Models
public class MainId
{
    [FromHeader(Name = "id")]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserId
{
    [FromHeader(Name = "userId")]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class OtherId
{
    [FromHeader(Name = "otherId")]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class AllHeaders
{
    // No FromHeaderAttribute here because the MainId property is not bound from Header - it's the child property that's bound from header
    // But RequiredAttribute is necessary here otherwise MainId == null would be a valid setup, violating the invariants expected in controller code
    [Required]
    public MainId MainId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public UserId UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public OtherId OtherId { get; set; }
}
```

And controller action method:

```
[HttpGet("/allThree")]
public string allThree(
    // You need the FromHeaderAttribute here to override the default binding logic for complex types, which is from request body for API controllers
    [FromHeader] AllHeaders headers)
{
    // be able to access all three headers here
    string h1 = headers.MainId.Id;
    string h2 = headers.UserId.Id;
    string h3 = headers.OtherId.Id;
}
```